# How to add "@" A HOST record in PowerDNS?

Tags: dns-zone, powerdns

In a typical web host's online ZONE editor, you'd refer to your primary IP Address as `@` and refer the `www` CNAME to that primary `@` A HOST.

I am trying to set up my own MySQL backend PowerDNS server on Ubuntu 14.04 and whenever I use `@` in an A HOST, it prints the following error:

`Error: You have invalid characters in your hostname.`

How do you refer to the primary IP Address in PowerDNS? Do you leave the record blank or is there a different way of going about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerDNS, all names are fully qualified, but without a trailing dot. So, not `www` but `www.example.com`. Not `@` or `` but `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! The PowerDNS documentation doesn't exactly make this clear.

Comment: If you have suggestions on how to improve, or what parts are confusing, please let us (PowerDNS) know!